# Add attachments based on user role to WooCommerce new user registration email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-attachments, user-roles

I want to add two pdf files to the new user registration e-mail of WooCommerce.

Because I have two specific user roles `customer` and `seller`.
I want to send all new sellers two pdf files from paths `$path1` and `$path3` and all new customers two pdf files from paths `$path2` and `$path3`.

I tried this in my `functions.php`

```php
function attach_to_email ( $attachments, $userrole ) { 

$root = ABSPATH;
$path1 = $root . '/media/AGB H.pdf';
$path2 = $root . '/media/AGB K.pdf';
$path3 = $root . '/media/W.pdf';

if ( $userrole === 'seller' ) {
   $attachments[] = $path1;
   $attachments[] = $path3;
} else {
   $attachments[] = $path2;
   $attachments[] = $path3;
}

return $attachments;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'attach_to_email', 10, 2 );
```

In the e-mail template for sellers I call:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', null, 'seller' );
```

But in the function, I always enter the else part and not the if-part. In addition, all e-mails are attached with the else-files now, not only the registration e-mails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only assign the attachments to the registration e-mail, you can use:

- The `$email_id`, where this is equal to `customer_new_account`

For the attachement path, linked to the theme, you can use:

- `get_stylesheet_directory()` for a child theme
- `get_template_directory()` for a parent theme
- I would also recommend not to use spacing in the file name of the pdf file

You can then assign the correct attachments based on the user role

---

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_email_attachments( $attachments, $email_id, $object, $email_object = null ) {
    // Use get_stylesheet_directory() for a child theme
    // Use get_template_directory() for a parent theme
    $path_1 = get_template_directory() . '/my-file-1.pdf';
    $path_2 = get_template_directory() . '/my-file-2.pdf';
    $path_3 = get_template_directory() . '/my-file-3.pdf';

    // Customer new account email
    if ( isset( $email_id ) && $email_id === 'customer_new_account' ) {         
        // Get user role(s)
        $roles = (array) $object->roles;
        
        // Seller
        if ( in_array( 'seller', $roles ) ) {
            $attachments[] = $path_1;
            $attachments[] = $path_3;           
        // Customer
        } elseif ( in_array( 'customer', $roles ) ) {
            $attachments[] = $path_2;
            $attachments[] = $path_3;
        }
    }
    
    return $attachments;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', 'filter_woocommerce_email_attachments', 10, 4 );
```

---

Code goes in `functions.php` file of your active theme. Tested in `WooCommerce 5.0.0`